# Destructuring 'req.body.data' into 'req.body'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am sending some data from the front end to the back end. I am trying to send `data` as an object to the back. When it arrives, it is obviously `req.body.data`, but should land in the backend as `req.body`. How do I destructure the request, either from the front or the back so that the back only receives `req.body`

front end

```
const { user } = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/auth/signup', {data});
```

Backend (what I want)

```
if(req.body.type === 'vendor') {
```

Right now the backend received (What i dont want)

```
if(req.body.data.type....)
```

Comment: May you show the code doing the destructuring? The only part is see is the user being destructured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your passing data as an object prop. Just pass it directly:

```
const { user } = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/auth/signup', data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending object with `data` property when sending request to the backend. What you should do is destruct that `data` object and send its property directly:

```js
const { user } = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/auth/signup', { ...data });
```

Comment: {...data} is the same as just data